# Trig substitution reversion issue $\pm$

Tags: calculus

I am working through the 100 integrals video on YouTube and I came across this question. I solved it correctly, but I want some clarification on a step that I made.

$$\displaystyle\int \frac{e^x\sqrt{e^x-1}}{e^x+3} \ dx$$

$$ u = e^x +3  \implies \int\frac{\sqrt{u-4}}{u} \ du = 2\int \frac{\sqrt{\frac{u}{4}-1}}{u} \ du $$

$$ u = 4\sec^2 (\theta) \implies 2\int \frac{\tan (\theta)\times8\sec^2 (\theta)\tan (\theta)}{4\sec^2 (\theta)} \ d\theta = 4 \int \tan^2 (\theta) \ d\theta = 4(\tan (\theta) - \theta)$$

I was now faced with the task of reverse substituting to get my answer into a function of $x$. So in order to achieve that I did

$$  u = 4\sec^2 (\theta) \implies u= 4(1+tan^2 (\theta)) \implies  \tan (\theta) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{u-4}{4}}$$

This is where the issues in my mind started to arise. How do we decide on which value of $\tan (\theta)$ to take? When I solved this question, I decided to take the positive value of $tan(\theta)$ and arrived at the correct answer, but I couldn't come up with any sound mathematical reasoning as to why taking the positive value was the correct thing to do here.

Comment: Firstly there is a typo, the integral would be $2\int \tan^2(\theta) d(\theta)$. Also, while taking square root, since these are functions, we cannot take both $\pm$, hence by convention the positive root is taken. $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: I think it's $4 \int \tan^2(\theta) \ d\theta$. $ \frac{\ du}{\ d\theta} = 8\sec^2 (\theta)\tan(\theta) \ d\theta $ which gives $2 \int \frac{\sqrt{\frac{4\sec^2 (\theta)}{4}-1}}{4\sec^2(\theta)}\ 8\sec^2(\theta)\tan(\theta) d \theta =  2\int \frac{\tan (\theta)}{4\sec^2(\theta)}\ 8\sec^2(\theta)\tan(\theta) d \theta = 4 \int tan^2 (\theta) \ d\theta  $ ?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I did not notice the $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, your original integrand is non-negative for all real $x \geq 0$, so the antiderivative sought is increasing. Only the $+$ branch of square root gives an increasing function of $x$.

In more detail, your work shows (including the prospective sign ambiguity and omitting the constants of integration)
\begin{align*}
  \frac{e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1}}{e^{x} + 3}\, dx
  &= \frac{\sqrt{u - 4}}{u}\, du\qquad u = e^{x} + 3 \\
  &= 4\int \tan^{2}\theta\, d\theta\qquad u = 4\sec^{2}\theta \\
  &= 4(\tan\theta - \theta) \\
  &= 4\biggl[\pm\sqrt{\frac{u - 4}{4}} \mp \arctan\sqrt{\frac{u - 4}{4}}\biggr] \\
  &= \pm4\biggl[\sqrt{\frac{e^{x} - 1}{4}} - \arctan\sqrt{\frac{e^{x} - 1}{4}}\biggr].
\end{align*}
Since $v - \arctan v$ is an increasing function of $v$, the expression in square brackets is increasing in $x$. This imposes the plus sign.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand it now. Have a good day!

Comment: You're welcome! Your practice of considering details and overall consistency, especially after having "found the answer", is a good one.